# How to filter messages that are sent/cc'ed to a specific email address?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

Does anyone know how to filter spam messages that are cc'ed or otherwise sent to another (specific) email address besides mine?

I hesitate to post this question on StackOverflow because spammers have been cc'ing my_first_name @ aol.com (not my email address, I don't know whose it is) in messages to me which somehow makes emails pass Gmail's spam detection.

Any spam message sent to me that is also sent to this other email address ends up in my inbox and I get quite a few of these every day. I've been marking them as spam for over a year now, but the algorithm hasn't picked up that I don't want emails that include this other email address. I didn't want to make public what appears to be a hack/loophole to avoid spam detection, but it's getting out of hand.

Neither email address in the photo is mine, but this is what appears with these emails I receive in my Gmail account.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the search filter `cc:` to find all emails that contain that email address. From which you can create a filter and perhaps "Delete it" (or "Apply a label" and "Archive it") such emails.

For example, search for `cc:someone@example.com` and hit the extended search options icon:

[image: Search using cc: filter]

Click <kbd>Create filter</kbd>

[image: Create filter]

Select the appropriate options. Unfortunately there does not seem to be the option to auto-flag as "SPAM", but you can perhaps choose "Delete it" (which remain in the "Trash" (or "Bin") for 30 days before being permanently deleted). Then Click <kbd>Create filter</kbd> to finally create the filter.

[image: Select options and create filter]

Reference:

- [Search operators you can use with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en-GB)